# Memory error by scipy library

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to use classification algorithms provided by scipy library but I am getting the following error:

```
  score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 349, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py", line 145, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 353, in kneighbors
    n_jobs=n_jobs, squared=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1240, in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1083, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 245, in euclidean_distances
    distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 186, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = ret.toarray()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 940, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 250, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 817, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

The problem is that I was not getting this error but suddenly, I am always getting this error. I am also running python 3 (64 bit version) and when I got this error, my RAM (8GB) was used on 30%.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Run a smaller problem?  In the error it is trying make a new array, probably to write calculations to.  There isn't enough remaining memory.  The array dimensions may be large, but there are other arrays memory as well. It's asked the OS for more space and gotten a 'no can do' message.

Comment: Reading the stack in more detail it appears to be doing some sort of pairwise distance calculation.  That's size of X times size of Y - potentially very big.  It is doing a sparse matrix multiplication which can save memory. Still it looks like your test sets are too big.

Comment: What's the size of `X_test`, `y_test`?

Comment: X is quite a large matrix (50000x30000) but it was working without any problem before. I reduced it to 50000x5000 but it is still giving me the error.

Comment: Maybe it's a lot denser than before.  Sparse size is a function of the number of nonzeros, not the shape.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked it and indeed, it is more denser. How can I solve such problem? Is there some option to compute the distances "per partes" so in small chunks? Because I need all those 5000 dimensions.

Comment: I know `numpy` and `sparse` better than `sklearn`, so can't help.